# Zope3 browser:page multiple interfaces

Tags: interface, zope, zope3, zcml

Let's say I have the following code in my configure.zcml file. I want my class to be implemented for another interface too, let's say `Interface2`

```
<browser:page
        for="Interface1"
        class="plone.app.content.browser.reviewlist.FullReviewListView"
        name="full_review_list"
        template="document_full_review_list.pt"
        permission="cmf.ReviewPortalContent" />
```

How do I declare this in my zcml file?

So long I tried the folowing:

```
<browser:page
       for="Interface1 Interface2"
       class="plone.app.content.browser.reviewlist.FullReviewListView"
       name="full_review_list"
       template="document_full_review_list.pt"
       permission="cmf.ReviewPortalContent" />
```

and

```
<browser:page
       for="Interface1"
       allowed_interface="Interface2"
       class="plone.app.content.browser.reviewlist.FullReviewListView"
       name="full_review_list"
       template="document_full_review_list.pt"
       permission="cmf.ReviewPortalContent" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to register it twice, once for each interface.

The name can be the same, without getting a **ConfigurationConflictError**, since a browserview is a named multi-adapter that adapts both an object providing a specific interface (i.e *Interface1* or *Interface2*) and the request.

So if the interface that the object is supposed to provide is different for each browserview registration, then there is no conflict.

```
<browser:page
        for="Interface1"
        class="plone.app.content.browser.reviewlist.FullReviewListView"
        name="full_review_list"
        template="document_full_review_list.pt"
        permission="cmf.ReviewPortalContent" />

<browser:page
        for="Interface2"
        class="plone.app.content.browser.reviewlist.FullReviewListView"
        name="full_review_list"
        template="document_full_review_list.pt"
        permission="cmf.ReviewPortalContent" />
```

Conversely, you can have two browserview registrations, for the same object interface (and with the same name), but with the discerning criteria being an interface provided by the request. That's what the *layer* attribute is for.